# Build error with Sencha Command

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-command

I just upgraded my app to Sencha Touch 2.1 and I'm now trying to build it for production. Unfortunately, I get the following error message :

```
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[DBG]       checking /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app for plugin.xml
[DBG]       checking /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/workspace for plugin.xml
[DBG]       checking /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/plugins/touch/current for plugin.xml
[DBG]       checking /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250 for plugin.xml
[DBG]       located plugin /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app/plugin.xml
[INF]       init-properties:
[INF]       init-sencha-command:
[INF]       init:
[INF]       -before-app-build:
[INF]       app-build-impl:
[DBG]       found sencha.cfg at /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250
[DBG]       found workspace at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/workspace
[DBG]       found app at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app
[DBG]       loading framework config from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch
[DBG]       found cmd at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch/cmd
[DBG]       Checking for framework config overrides
[DBG]       resolving framework config overrides for 'touch'
[DBG]       Detected framework version 2.1.0.447
[DBG]       using framework config override '/Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/plugins/touch/current'
[INF]       production:
[INF]       -before-init-local:
[INF]       -init-local:
[INF]       -after-init-local:
[INF]       init-local:
[INF]       find-cmd:
[INF]       -before-init:
[INF]       -init:
[DBG]       Initialize Sencha Cmd with prefix = ''
[DBG]       found sencha.cfg at /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250
[DBG]       found workspace at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/workspace
[DBG]       found app at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app
[DBG]       loading framework config from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch
[DBG]       found cmd at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch/cmd
[DBG]       Checking for framework config overrides
[DBG]       resolving framework config overrides for 'touch'
[DBG]       Detected framework version 2.1.0.447
[DBG]       using framework config override '/Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/plugins/touch/current'
[DBG]       adding /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha.jar to classpath
[INF]       -after-init:
[INF]       init:
[INF]       -before-build:
[INF]       sass:
[INF]       -before-sass:
[INF]       -sass:
[INF]       [shellscript] identical ../css/app.css 
[INF]       -after-sass:
[INF]       page:
[INF]       -before-page:
[INF]       -page:
[INF]       building application
[INF]       Deploying your application to /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/build/sencha/production
[DBG]       copying all assets
[DBG]       copying file /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/app.js
[INF]       Copied app.js
[DBG]       copying file /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/css/app.css
[INF]       Copied resources/css/app.css
[DBG]       copying all extras
[DBG]       copying from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/images to /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/build/sencha/production/resources/images
[INF]       Copied /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/images
[DBG]       copying from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/icons to /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/build/sencha/production/resources/icons
[INF]       Copied /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/icons
[DBG]       copying from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/startup to /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/build/sencha/production/resources/startup
[INF]       Copied /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/resources/startup
[INF]       Resolving your application dependencies (file:////Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/index.html)
[DBG]       found sencha.cfg at /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250
[DBG]       found workspace at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/workspace
[DBG]       found app at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app
[DBG]       loading framework config from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch
[DBG]       found cmd at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch/cmd
[DBG]       Checking for framework config overrides
[DBG]       resolving framework config overrides for 'touch'
[DBG]       Detected framework version 2.1.0.447
[DBG]       using framework config override '/Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/plugins/touch/current'
[INF]       Compiling app.js and dependencies
[DBG]       running compiler with options : 'compile --ignore=src/locale,src/platform,auth2/Auth.js,scroller/Infinite.js --options=debug:false,logger:no,minVersion:3,product:touch union --recursive --file=app.js and concatenate -out=/Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/build/sencha/production/app.js'
[DBG]       found sencha.cfg at /Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250
[DBG]       found workspace at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/workspace
[DBG]       found app at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app
[DBG]       loading framework config from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch
[DBG]       found cmd at /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/touch/cmd
[DBG]       Checking for framework config overrides
[DBG]       resolving framework config overrides for 'touch'
[DBG]       Detected framework version 2.1.0.447
[DBG]       using framework config override '/Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/plugins/touch/current'
[DBG]       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
[ERR]       BUILD FAILED
[ERR]       com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]       /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.setRecordingComments(Z)V (<Unknown source>#461) in <Unknown source> at line number 461
[ERR]           at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:43)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:104)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:182)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.SenchaCommandTask.doExecute(SenchaCommandTask.java:58)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.BaseAntTask.execute(BaseAntTask.java:22)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:72)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:87)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:91)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BaseNamePathCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:135)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:106)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:71)
[ERR]       Caused by: /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:126: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]       /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.setRecordingComments(Z)V (<Unknown source>#461) in <Unknown source> at line number 461
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:80)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommand.execute(AntCommand.java:75)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]           ... 31 more
[ERR]       Caused by: /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.setRecordingComments(Z)V (<Unknown source>#461) in <Unknown source> at line number 461
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.toBuildException(ReflectUtil.java:183)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.throwBuildException(ReflectUtil.java:166)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:110)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDef.executeScript(ScriptDef.java:350)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDefBase.execute(ScriptDefBase.java:50)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[ERR]           ... 52 more
[ERR]       Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.setRecordingComments(Z)V (<Unknown source>#461) in <Unknown source> at line number 461
[ERR]           at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:156)
[ERR]           at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:170)
[ERR]           at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
[ERR]           ... 69 more
[ERR]       Total time: 21 seconds
[ERR]       com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/app/sencha/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:120: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.setRecordingComments(Z)V (<Unknown source>#461) in <Unknown source> at line number 461
```

I managed to compile the app by enabling V2 compatibility mode like explained here :

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command_app-section-3

So what could be the reason why it does not compile without this mode enabled ?

I just went through all my views and double checked the requires statements, they're all there. Also, I don't override any component in my app.

**Update**

It compiles without errors on one of my coworker's mac.
I'm on Mountain Lion and this is my `java -version`

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is a system env variable pointing at an outdated version (maybe rhino vers)

Comment: I updated download the latest version of Rhino and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post how did you updated Rhino. i am unable to do it:(

Answer (score 3):

It could be trying to do a sass build with the app build(2.1 does that now), you need compass installed for it to work, but sometimes even with it installed it doesn't. I found the easiest way is to build the sass yourself and add this:

```
skip.sass=1
```

To the **sencha.cfg** file in touch\cmd.

Add it before the long dotted line, the first section.

See if that helps :)

Comment: When Compass is not installed the error looks more like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664736/sencha-cmd-3-0-0-250-build-error/13670208#13670208 Anyway I still tried skipping sass and it still does not work without the v2deps flag on. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Sencha Touch 2.1, I had the same problem but installed the compass gem instead and it worked, did not mess with rhino.

just ran gem install compass from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

These errors are caused by errors when resolving dependencies. You actually [linked](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command_app-section-3) to the explanation. Make sure your requires/using statements are defined everywhere.

> The new Sencha Cmd compiler is used by default to determine
>   dependencies. Unlike previous releases, the compiler determines
>   dependencies by processing source code (application and framework). In
>   some cases this can lead to missing dependencies, that is,
>   dependencies that were automatically detected in previous releases but
>   are not detected by the compiler.
>
> The ideal solution in this case is to add the missing requires
>   statements to resolve the issue. This may include switching overrides
>   to the new, named form, such as:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.patches.foo.Bar', {
   override: 'Ext.foo.Bar',
   ...
});
```

> This enables overrides to be required by their name and therefore for the compiler to process them in the right sequence.
>
> If that effort needs to be postponed, you can enable V2 compatibility
>   mode (based on launching your application via file system protocol
>   inside of a headless WebView to extract dependencies).

Comment: Like I said, I double checked every requires statement and they are none missing. Also I'm not overriding any component. I also forgot to mention that compiling works on a co-worker's mac.