# Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.250 build error

Tags: sencha-touch-2

OS: Win7
HTTP Server: Tomcat7

I am new to Sencha. Just installed latest sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial+Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.250.

Could run "sencha" command under SDK dir.
Could run "sencha generate app GS ../GS" to generate a sample project.

I didn't change anything from the newly generated project GS and tried to build it using command: sencha app build production

But I got the following stack trace:

```
C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS>sencha app build production
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[INF]           init-properties:
[INF]           init-sencha-command:
[INF]           init:
[INF]           -before-app-build:
[INF]           app-build-impl:
[INF]           production:
[INF]           -before-init-local:
[INF]           -init-local:
[INF]           -after-init-local:
[INF]           init-local:
[INF]           find-cmd:
[INF]           -before-init:
[INF]           -init:
[INF]           -after-init:
[INF]           init:
[INF]           -before-build:
[INF]           sass:
[INF]           -before-sass:
[INF]           -sass:
[INF]           [shellscript] '''compass''' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[INF]           [shellscript]
[INF]           [shellscript] C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS\resources\sass>compass compile --boring --force
[INF]           [shellscript] operable program or batch file.
[ERR]           BUILD FAILED
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]           C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:92: The following error occurred while executing this l
ine:
[ERR]           jar:file:/C:/ZZ/Others/Startup/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:347: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:43)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:104)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:182)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.SenchaCommandTask.doExecute(SenchaCommandTask.java:58)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.BaseAntTask.execute(BaseAntTask.java:22)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:72)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:87)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:91)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BaseNamePathCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:135)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:106)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:71)
[ERR]           Caused by: C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:100: The following error occurred while exec
uting this line:
[ERR]           C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:92: The following error occurred while executing this l
ine:
[ERR]           jar:file:/C:/ZZ/Others/Startup/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:347: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:80)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommand.execute(AntCommand.java:75)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]                   ... 31 more
[ERR]           Caused by: C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:92: The following error occurred while execu
ting this line:
[ERR]           jar:file:/C:/ZZ/Others/Startup/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:347: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:401)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[ERR]                   ... 52 more
[ERR]           Caused by: jar:file:/C:/ZZ/Others/Startup/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:347: shellscript returne
d: 1
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
[ERR]                   at net.sf.antcontrib.platform.ShellScriptTask.execute(ShellScriptTask.java:132)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
[ERR]                   at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
[ERR]                   at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
[ERR]           ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
[ERR]                   ... 64 more
[ERR]           Total time: 1 second
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\ZZ\Others\Startup\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\GS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:92: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/ZZ/Others/Startup/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:347: shellscript returned: 1
```

Could somebody tell what am i missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear :

```
'''compass''' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

You need to install `compass`, otherwise Sencha CMD can't compile the CSS.

Hope this helps

Comment: I solved this problem by following this answer. It looks like although compass is for css optimization but you HAVE TO do this if you use sencha command. So you need to install compass first.

Answer (score 5):

just add

```
skip.sass=1
```

in

> PROJECT_FOLDER/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg

and

> PROJECT_FOLDER/.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg

Comment: This helped to get past the error mentioned. Seems it was sufficient to only add to .sencha/app/sencha.cfg