# Sencha Touch "Unknown Command: 'include' " error

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

When I try to build my first app on sencha touch, I get that error:

```
com.sencha.extensions.ExArg: Unknown command "include"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626174/2877080) answer or [that](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282457-BUILD-FAILED-com.sencha.exceptions.ExArg-Unknown-command-quot-include-quot) suggestions haven't resolved.

I use apache server, if it's required for answer.

Thanks for response.

Comment: What Sencha Touch/Cmd versions ? What is the command you are running ?

Comment: @user272735 version is 2.3.1 an my command is `sencha generate app MyApp ../myapp`